# Use variable from a previous DO clause

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a .sql script like this:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE     
    prev_count := (SELECT count(*) FROM ...);
END$$;

UPDATE [...]

DO $$
    DECLARE     
    cur_count := (SELECT count(*) FROM ...);
    BEGIN
    ASSERT cur_count = prev_count, 'Mismatch';
END$$;
```

In which I get some value, modify the database, and expect a new value to match an old value. However, I get errors like this:

```
psql:migration.sql:163: ERROR:  column "prev_count" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT cur_count = prev_count
                              ^
QUERY:  SELECT cur_count = prev_count
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at ASSERT
```

I can't tell if this is a scoping issue because of the anonymous block, and why it's attempting to treat my variables like columns. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried single anonymous block? **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e790dcb8a8e948f4fd0a69dca697f7cc)**

Comment: Looks like a scope issue and it is assuming `prev_count` is a column because the variable name `prev_count` no longer exists in the current scope.  If this is a repeated task with a static update function I would probably just create a stored proc

Comment: @lad2025 I hadn't, thanks for the idea + code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual `DO` executes an anonymous code block that:

> ... is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void. It is parsed and executed a single time...

So it is a function that returns `VOID`. In that sense `prev_count` only exists in the first `DO`.

To avoid this, you could create a TEMP table and insert the `prev_count` in the first `DO` so you can use it anywhere in the transaction.